# Installing VPN servers that support PPTP, L2TP and openVPN protocols

Tags: openvpn, pptp, l2tp, network-protocols

Looking for VPN Server that support PPTP, L2TP and OpenVPN Protocols, also these servers must use the same data base so each account created on any of these servers must work across all the other connected servers.

Comment: Product and service recommendations, including if-exists queries, are off topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been far too vague in my opinion, still here goes;

In terms of a single VPN server that does all that, I only know of one: [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/)

With regards to them all using the same authentication back end, well that isn't going to work on pfSense by default. I like to virtualise them, so you can have the VM replicating around so the same configuration is in multiple places. That would cover your requirement.

The only other way I see is if you are a Window shop, use Active Directory and ISA. You can run all three VPNs on Windows Server (either natively or as 3rd part services such as with openVPN) and then configure them all to authenticate to AD.

Ultimately though, I think you need to give some more specifications, but be weary you don't turn this into a shopping thread.